# where can i find an implementation of the coordination language linda in c?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, linda

I am trying to find an implementation of the language in c that is actually based on the language standards ,here is a simple example

```
#include "linda.h"

int worker(int num)
{
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<num; i++)
    out("hello, world");
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  int result;
  eval("worker", worker(5));
  in("hello, world");
  in("hello, world");
  in("hello, world");
  in("hello, world");
  in("hello, world");
  in("worker", ? result);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: already tried the first 20 results on google , msn and the external links on Wikipedia if that matters!! and they gave me a vote down :(

Comment: Which `OS` are you using and which `compiler` with `version` do you have?

Comment: OS windows or linux whatever you find @Rizier123

Comment: Does my answer help's you with the answer update? Or where are you stuck?

Comment: only if those who gave me a vote down gave me the answer i am looking for instead...

Comment: I think the only had a bad day :/ I mean your question is good.

Answer (score 2):

So directly to your question:

`Where can i find an implementation of the coordination language linda in c?`
Here: http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~wongwf/linda.html

You can download it and use it!

If you download it you should get this:

```
linda //dir
  |
  | - linda.c     //file
  | - linda.h     //file
  | - primes.c    //file
  | - README.txt  //file
```

But you have to know:

- You must call `linda_init()` before you do linda stuff
- You must call `linda_end()`before exiting
- There is no `eval()` function but you can use `spawn()`
- The library `varargs.h` is outdated! So i would recommend you to use: `stdarg.h`

  - So that means it could be that you have to rewrite stuff!

So there is only one thing todo!
Download it and get started!

**EDIT:**

Another way you could go is to download a `Linda-C` compiler and write your programs in Linda-C (`*.clc`).

So but back to library from above:
I got a program working with linda in c with this library!

I have: `GNU GCC compiler(tdm64-1) 4.7.1 MinGW64`

What you have to look out for:

- In `linda.h` you have to change the include `sys/varargs.h` to `stdarg.h` since varargs is outdated!

  - That means also that you have to change in `linda.c` all `va_arg()` calls and change the following type:

    - `float` -> `double`
    - `char`  -> `int`
- After you have done that you should be able to compile `linda.c` to `linda.o` with this command line:

  - `gcc -c -O linda.c` (Also it could be that you have to direct to the `gcc.exe` so that the command `gcc` is known in `Windows cmd`)

So as an example:

Path to `gcc compiler`:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin"
```

Path to `linda library`:

```
"C:\Users\xy\Downloads\linda\linda"
```

So now if you open `cmd` and type in: `gcc --version` and it's not found you have to direct to the `gcc.exe` file like this (otherwise your fine and you don't have to direct to the compiler dir):

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin"
```

So if your in the `directory` where `gcc.exe` is located you should be able to execute that command: `gcc --version`

And from there you can execute the command to create `linda.o`! Which looks like this in this example:

```
gcc -c -O C:\Users\xy\Downloads\linda\linda\linda.c
```

If all worked out! You should end up with the file `linda.o` in your compiler directory

And now with the file `linda.o` you can compile `primes.c` (Which is in this library as an example) and get a `linda` programm in `c` working! with the following line:

```
gcc -o C:\Users\xy\Downloads\linda\linda\primes -O C:\Users\xy\Downloads\linda\linda\primes.c C:\Users\xy\Downloads\linda\linda\linda.o -lpthread -lm
```

With this line you should end up with the `.exe` file: `primes.exe`! Which you can copy in the compiler directory and execute! If you don't have it in this dir then `lpthreadGC2_64.dll` is unknown and it can't be executed!

- Few side notes to the compiling of this example:

  - lpthread -> pthread library
  - lm       -> math library
  - Also i would recommend you to add the following line in the `primes.c` file at the end so that if you execute it, the window does not close instant: `system("pause");`

- Also for your problem that with this library you can't use `eval()` there are a few workarounds/ solutions:

  - You can make a `for` loop and call your functions multiple times! (Since the function you call with `spawn()` has to have `void` as `return type`)
  - You can define a constant with: `#define CALLS 5` and use this in the function itself for the commands to execute in a `for` loop or also in the `main` function to call `spawn()` multiple times
  - I think there are more ways to solve this!

So all that said. Your program should look something like this:

```
#include "linda.h"

#define NUM 5

void worker() {

  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
      out("%s", "hello, world");

}

int main() {

    int result;

    spawn(worker);
    in("%s", "hello, world");
    in("%s", "hello, world");
    in("%s", "hello, world");
    in("%s", "hello, world");
    in("%s", "hello, world");
    in("%s?d", "worker", &result);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Hope this helps you!

Cheers

Comment: unfortunately my friend , i already have  seen this link you provided ,but it didn't for me :(   for example the spawn function only takes a call to a void function with no params , that is certainly not following the language standards.

Comment: @QuakeCore updated my answer with a few extra info's and hint's! Hope it helps you and you get it working!

Comment: i really appreciate your interest @Rizier123, the problem with this implementation is the spawn function it takes a call to a void function with no arguments , but its expected to take  a call to a function with any return type , and any number of arguments. there might be a work around to implement any program to match up with this implementation (like you did) and thats totally fine with me , but believe me i am not the one who is making the rules here :).

Comment: @QuakeCore You could search for a `Linda-C compiler`, but then you would program in `Linda-C`, otherwise i don't see a way around to write your own `API`(->Github project and get started)! Also this library is not update as you can see yourself, so i don't think there is a newer API.. (OR you write a `Interpreter` that convert's your `C` program in a `Linda` program)

Comment: you are my only hope , you said "Another way you could go is to download a Linda-C compiler and write your programs in Linda-C (*.clc)" , I've searched the entire web and couldn't find it. hnestly i am not sure exactly what i am looking for... :(

Comment: @QuakeCore I only can give you this help: https://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~jbasney/honors/thesis.html i never programmed in Linda so i'm slowly at the limit of my ideas!

Comment: sorry for wasting your time searching for something as useless as this language (in my opinion) :) ,anyway thank you.